# Watchdog to stop power supply

Tags: power-supply, watchdog

I want to stop supplying power for a short moment if a watchdog has not received a reset order for a while.

Shutting down power is important as this is the only way for some buggy device to function again.

More details:
Buggy device run on 5V. GPIO voltage can be 5V or 3.3V. In normal operation the whole circuit is consuming about 0.5A sometime peaks overs 2.5A for a really short moment.

We can consider that the GPIO can freeze and therefore stay in +5V position.

Comment: What voltage does said buggy device run on, and what voltage is the GPIO running at?  Also, how much current does said buggy device draw?

Comment: The term you are looking for is supervisor ic or reset ic

Comment: Yeah -- depending on his voltage rails, it may be possible to do this with nothing more than a SVS chip, a PMOS, and a few ceramic caps.

Comment: Is the GPIO on the device that may freeze up, or on some other (reliable) device that is monitoring it?

Answer (score 2):

You can purchase supervisory chips that will provide a reset pulse if the WDT input has not been toggled in a certain length of time. For example, the Analog Devices [ADM83xx series](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADM8316_8318_8319_8320_8321_8322.pdf), but there are many others. The WDT will provide the pulse if the input gets stuck high or low, or simply fails to respond in time.

You could also design a circuit that has that function, but the integrated chips are very small and not unreasonably expensive.

Use a parametric search and look at the datasheets to find a suitable product if you want a fully integrated version. The general category is supervisory chips, but not all incorporate a watchdog. You can probably find windowed watchdogs too which will reset the system if the pulses come too frequently as well as too infrequently.

[image]

If the reset pulse that the device provides (the above type has a number of options for pulse width) is not sufficient, you could stretch it with a monostable multivibrator chip.

Interrupting the power to the subsystem is then merely a matter of connecting a suitable high-side power switch to the /RESET output. You may need to control the ramp-up current to keep from causing a glitch on the supply due to decoupling capacitance on the switched side, and/or you may need to actively discharge said decoupling capacitance to positively reset the circuit within the available time.

Needless to say, this is a nasty bandaid fix and it would be better to solve the root cause first.